# Does not work ng-select

Tags: angular, typescript

Why the data does not appear in SELECT? When I click on the opening list there is empty, although it must store information. Where could I make a mistake?

Component.ts:

```
...
spr_wellpads: Array<ComboboxItem>;
loading: boolean = false;
...
constructor(
private servSprWellpad: SprWellpadService
)
...

    ngOnInit() {     
...

        this.loading = true;
        this.servSprWellpad.getSprWellpads().subscribe(
            result => {
                this.loading = false;
                this.spr_wellpads = result.spr_wellpads.map(r => ({
                    value: r.spr_oilfields_id.toString()
                }));
            },
            error => {
                this.toastManager.error(getErrorTextFromJSON(error.json()), 'Error')
            }); 
    }
...
```

html:

```
<ng-select [(ngModel)]="sprWellpad.spr_oilfields_id" [options]="spr_wellpads"
                        [notFoundMsg]="'Not is not found'"
                        [allowClear]="true"></ng-select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `ng-select` options accepts `[{ id : your_id , name : your_value }]` pairs , and you were passing the `[{ value : your_value }]`

You need to change this :

```
this.spr_wellpads = result.spr_wellpads.map(r => ({
    value: r.spr_oilfields_id.toString()
}));
```

To :

```
this.spr_wellpads = result.spr_wellpads.map(r => ({
    id : r.spr_oilfields_id,
    name: r.spr_oilfields_id.toString()
}));
```

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://plnkr.co/edit/NaQ27M?p=preview)**